# Deleting repeated emails in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, forwarding, duplicate

I have a small pet peeve which I find really annoying and which I would like to find an automated way to not deal with repeatedly.

I receive emails from two separate mailing lists, one of which tends to echo the other one. Thus, whenever there is an email in mailing list A of the form

> From: Sender A
>
> Subject: Seminar today!
>
> Body:
>
> (Original email text)

it is almost immediately forwarded in mailing list B:

> From: Sender B
>
> Subject: FWD: Seminar today!
>
> Body:
>
> Please see details of today's seminar below:
>
> ---
>
> (Original email text)

where the text "Please see details of today's seminar below" is usually handwritten, contains essentially no information, and may sometimes not be present. Sender A and Sender B are always the same. I would like to get rid of the second email whenever there is already an email in my inbox which contains `(Original email text)` and with subject `Seminar today!` (i.e. minus the `FWD:`).

I usually delete these manually but they add to the clutter. **Is there an automatic way to delete such duplicates directly?** Note that these are not 'exact' duplicates in the sense of the [Remove Duplicate Messages](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/remove-duplicate-messages-alte/) extension, in that they are two separate emails which nevertheless contain the same information.

I am running Thunderbird 24.2.0 over Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: No, that text is typically handwritten and varies from email to email (or may not be present), and rarely if ever contains actual information. The forwarded message is always included and it always matches an email which is already in my inbox.

Comment: In a previous thread; see amended question.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I saw that thread, but that is all for duplicates of the *same* email, not very-similar emails that contain the same information.

Comment: I have a concern about your request (or I still don't understand). You want (I think) a program to read an email, remember the content and find where that content is repeated in another email (at any point in the thread) and mark this as a duplicate (which it is). This software would surely detect nearly all emails - as soon as you reply to an email and get a response, technically this would be considered a duplicate since it contains the original email.

Comment: Not quite. I want to set up a filter, or similar construct, which will detect emails specifically from Sender B, which contain the forwarded subject line and body of an email specifically by Sender A within a short time window. This class of emails is narrow enough in my case.